# How Do I Reference a Registered API?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm working with filtered data in DataTables, and somebody was nice enough in the forums section to show how to work with the filtered dataset.  My problem is the set it up as an API, and I don't know how to reference it. I have no experience with APIs so I'm not really sure what I'm talking about, but I'm assuming this function gets called automatically and a "variable" is set/registered in the API.  Is this correct? How do I retrieve the variable to work with it?

Here's the function they put together:

```
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register('filteredData()', function() {
return this.settings()[0].aiDisplay
    .map(function(it) {
        return this.data()[it];
    }, this);
});
```

And here's a link to the forum site:

[DataTables Filtered Data API](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/79929/#Comment_79929)

As always, thanks for helping me expand my knowledge!!

Comment: Since the registered method not is targeting a specific subset of the API you can do `table.filteredData()`, `table.rows().filteredData()`, `table.columns().filteredData()` etc..You get the picture :)

Comment: @davidkonrad, this should be an answer even if it's a short one! After I see your correct comments over and over, I feel like cheating answering.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, Just go ahead and answer :) Could not find any duplicate so there is certainly room for an entry; on the other hand I have not so much to add. I believe you have made a real extension yourself,  so perhaps you have some good insight to share.